# Oracle graph studio slow execution time

Tags: oracle, oracle-graph

I am comparing graph databases so I tried oracle graph studio, however when I ran a query that takes less than 20 ms on most other databases (Neptune, neo4j, tigergraph) it takes over a second on graph studio, I tried other queries with similar results (the execution time is greater than 1 second). So I am asking if there is a way to optimize queries in graph studio or is there a certain limitation that requires 1 second to over come so more complex queries on larger databases will be comparable to other competitors as they claim?

Most of my other databases used 2 vcpus while I only use 1 for graph studio so could that also be a factor for the almost 100x slower performance?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Could you share the example queries you have tried?

Comment: just a simple query to get all the ancestors of a node, nothing more. The graph has over 1 million nodes though

Comment: It is helpful if you can share the query. Also, is the graph loaded on memory?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM MATCH (x) -/:EDGES*/-> (o)
ON graph1
WHERE o.C_ID = '523A1A68-514F-42B4-9527-703682F6AB27'    and yes the graph was loaded to memory

Comment: Thanks. The query looks simple. How do you measure the elapsed time? If you are looking at the output at the right-bottom of each notebook paragraph, it includes not only execution time but also all overheads in the interpreter and the communication between the interpreter and the server.